# Laravel sometimes vs sometimes|required

Tags: validation, laravel, required

What is the difference between `sometimes|required|email` and `sometimes|email` in Laravel validation?I've read [this discussion from laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/what-does-sometimes-validation-rule-truly-mean-confused) but still it is ambiguous for me

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From the docs:

> In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a
>   field only if that field is present in the input array. To quickly
>   accomplish this, add the sometimes rule to your rule list

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

If I could simplify it, I would say `sometimes` means, only apply the rest of the validation rules if the field shows up in the request. Imagine `sometimes` is like an if statement that checks if the field is present in the request/input before applying any of the rules.

I use this rule when I have some javascript on a page that will *disable* a field, as when a field is disabled it won't show up in the request. If I simply said `required|email` the validator is always going to apply the rules whereas using the `sometimes` rule will only apply the validation if the field shows up in the request! Hope that makes sense.

Examples:

```
input: []
rules: ['email' => 'sometimes|required|email']
result: pass, the request is empty so sometimes won't apply any of the rules

input: ['email' => '']
rules: ['email' => 'sometimes|required|email']
result: fail, the field is present so the required rule fails!

input: []
rules: ['email' => 'required|email']
result: fail, the request is empty and we require the email field!
```

Comment: thanks. as i understand `sometimes` refers to POST key and `require` refers to its value.so if a field is required both key and value should be present in POST .am i right?

Comment: You could actually apply the validation process to any old array actually and it could therefore be `POST` or `GET`. And yes, that's actually a good way of explaining it. You can of course combine the `sometimes` and `required` rule. If you want further details of how it works in the framework you can always check the source: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L262 and the tests: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/tests/Validation/ValidationValidatorTest.php#L14