# Does Laravel validation rule default to sometimes?

Tags: laravel, validation, required

If you create a validation rule in Laravel, but leave out |required and just use, say the email rule. What does it default to?

For example

```
$request->validate([
    'email' => 'email'
]);
```

Are these validation rules equal?

```
$request->validate([
    'email' => 'sometimes|email'
]);

// vs

$request->validate([
    'email' => 'email'
]);
```

Apologies if this has been answered before. I tried my very best to search for similar questions, but I may have used the wrong words (not sure how to phrase this for a Google/Stack Overflow search).

Answer (score 1):

```
$request->validate([
    'email' => 'email'
]);
```

This will *always* validate the `email` key, even if empty, to be a valid `email` format.

```
$request->validate([
    'email' => 'sometimes|email'
]);
```

This will *only* validate the `email` key **if** the key is present in `$request->all()`.

---

So the difference is that with `sometimes` you'll only validate it if the `$request` object contains it, whilst otherwise it would always validate against the key.

If I could simplify it, I would say sometimes means, only apply the rest of the validation rules if the field shows up in the request. Imagine sometimes is like an if statement that checks if the field is present in the request/input before applying any of the rules.

It can be a tedious thing to wrap ones head around, but here is some examples:

```
input: []
rules: ['email' => 'sometimes|email']
result: pass, the request is empty so sometimes won't apply any of the rules

input: ['email' => '1']
rules: ['email' => 'sometimes|email']
result: fail, the field is present though invalid email so the email rule fails!

input: []
rules: ['email' => 'email']
result: fail, the request is empty so email is invalid!
```

Comment: If the answer match with other questions, you may duplicate it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35839650/9978078

Comment: If I POST a HTTP request with no body (just {}), i.e. no 'email', then the rule ['email' => 'email'] is still valid. The controller returns 200 OK. However with an empty body but rule set to ['email' => 'required|email'] it returns 422 as expected. Thats why I initially thought that ['email' => 'email'] and ['email' => 'sometimes|email'] was equal since the controller response is 200 OK.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have never used the `sometimes` rule once. According to the docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

> you may wish to run validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the input array. To quickly accomplish this, add the sometimes rule to your rule list

If I understand correctly, this largely depends on your frontend implementation. If you are using regular html `<form>` elements where you have an input with `name="email"`, it will send a key named `email` as soon as you submit the form.

So in order to NOT send such key, you have to remove it from the form, or manually make a HTTP request (so disregarding any HTML form) such that you can decide your own input fields.