# Can you explain the difference betwen laravels' "sometimes" and "nullable" validator on an example?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I struggle to understand the difference between sometimes and nullable.

Every time I ask people just send me to documentation and that sound like they don't know the difference too. I've read documentation multiple times and I don't get how that works

Can you give me minimalistic sample of validator with data where changing sometimes to nullable changes the effect of validation?

Comment: [Sometimes Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35839414/laravel-sometimes-vs-sometimesrequired/35839650#35839650)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a minimal example here it is:

```
$validator = Validator::make([
    'a' => null
], [
    'a' => 'sometimes|integer'
]);
dump($validator->passes()); // false
$validator = Validator::make([
    'a' => null
], [ 
    'a' => 'nullable|integer'
]);

dump($validator->passes()); // true
```

Some notes: There's a middleware included in your `Kernel.php` by default called `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` which when commented out will make data coming as empty from forms to be basically treated as missing instead of null.

`sometimes|integer` is functionally identical to `integer` in this particular case because `a` can either be missing, or an integer if it's not missing.

In general `sometimes` is like a "guard", you apply the validation rules on the right side of the guard if the field is present but you do nothing when absent. Otherwise without `sometimes` the validation rules always run but all (except the `required*` rules) pass when the field is missing.

Comment: Thanks for the example. As an addition and after tests, when `a` input is not provided in payload, both validators return true.

Comment: Yes that is true. Only `required*` validation rules fail when the field is missing all other rules pass

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your request contains: `{name: 'value'}`

I believe that:

- `sometimes` means that the `name` fields can be present or not in the request body. Means it'll pass validation even if there is no `name` field on the request
- `nullable` means that the field must be present, but the field value can be `null`. But in this case, you have to provide the `name` field even with a null value.

Let's say you have form with a particular input that is displayed only depending on previous input values. So this field is not always available: you can use `sometimes` as its "normal" that the user won't always submit this field.
In the other hand, if the field is always displayed but not required: you'll allow `null` values, but not the fact that the field is missing in the body: as it may be a bot or anything else that changed your form: not correct.

Comment: There's a bit of nuance here. `nullable` fields can also not be present in the input unless they are also `required`. The difference is `nullable` allows a field to be absent or empty when present, `sometimes` allows a field to be absent but does not allow it to be empty when present

Comment: Oh thanks for those clarifications @apokryfos. So if I get you right, using only "nullable" has no effect?

Comment: Generally, `nullable` tends to be used in combination with other rules. It doesn't make much sense on its own

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. When u have the nullable validation rule that means that the field that it is associated with it can have a null value when it is sent making it optional but it will always be validated.

```
    'test_field1'            => 'nullable|integer'
```

On the other hand the sometimes validation rule applies all other validation rules associated with a field only when that field is sent via the request. For example :

```
    'test_field1'            => 'sometimes|integer'
```

This means that test_field1 will bi validated if it is an integer only when the request data has that field.

You can read more about the validation rules in the official laravel documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-nullable

Comment: I've really googled first, and I've seen that your response is first hit, I want the data that will pass one of those tests and not the other, can you provide it?