# Difference between sometimes|required|email and sometimes|email validation rules

Tags: laravel

What effect does `required` have in `sometimes|required|email`?

My understanding of these rules is:

- **sometimes**: Only validates the field if it is present in the request
- **required**: The field must be present in the request and must not be empty
- **email**: The field must be a valid email address

The part I am confused about is why `required` is needed when `email` should be sufficient.

For example, if the value is `''`, `required` will fail as the value is empty, and `email` will fail because the email is not valid. But if we change the rules to `sometimes|email`, and pass in `''` again, `email` will fail because it is not a valid email, effectively doing the job of `required`.

It seems to me that `sometimes|required|email` and `sometimes|email` are equivalent, yet `sometimes|required|email` is listed as an example in the Laravel docs (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-when-present).

I also checked out this question ([Laravel sometimes vs sometimes|required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35839414/laravel-sometimes-vs-sometimesrequired)) but it doesn't seem to answer the question.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

According to the laravel docs (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-email), the email validator rule is implemented by the egulias/email-validator package (https://github.com/egulias/EmailValidator/blob/3.x/src/Validation/RFCValidation.php) which by default only uses RFCValidation. The implementation of this requires the email value to be a string. Adding required before this will cause the validator to fail before the email validator is called preventing you passing it an empty value which could be null or undefined which the email validator can't handle.